# Comparing dates and auto populate field issue in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, date

I want to compare today date with user selected date. Based on user selected date, I have to some calculation and store result date in some date. For example, Case 1: If the current date is less than 3 months of user selected date, then I have to assign resulted date with the value of adding 3 months of user selected date. Case 2: If the current date is more than 3 months of user selected date, then I have to assign resulted date with the next year of user selected date.

For that, I have two fields in my HTML. One for user selected date and other for **Auto Populated** resulted date.

Am facing an issue when trying to compare the dates and auto populate field. I want to display the resulted date immediately once the user selects the date. I Am using (change) event for that. But it's not working.

Also while comparing dates I got an error like cannot assign the number to date. I am using Ng Datetime Picker for picking a date because my model in web API is in the type of DateTime. Anyone, please help to fix these issues. Thanks in Advance.

My Html:

```
    <div class="row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-md-3">User Selected Date</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="UserSelectedDate" #UserSelectedDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.UserSelectedDate" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3"
              [owlDateTime]="dt3" (change)="dateCalculation($event)">
            <owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" #dt3></owl-date-time>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label class="col-form-label col-md-3">Resulted Date</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" disabled name="ResultedDate" #ResultedDate="ngModel"
              [(ngModel)]="model.ResultedDate">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Typescript File:

```
    model: Model;

    dateCalculation(event: Date) {
    const today = new Date();
    const day = today.getDate();
    const month= today.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = today.getFullYear();

    if (month < (this.model.UserSelectedDate.getMonth() + 4 )) {
      this.model.ResultedDate.setMonth(this.model.UserSelectedDate.getMonth() +4);
      return this.model.ResultedDate;
    }
    else if (month > (this.model.UserSelectedDate.getMonth() + 4 )) {
      this.model.ResultedDate.setMonth(this.model.UserSelectedDate.getFullYear() + 1); //I know this is wrong..Don't know how to achieve my above condition.
      return this.model.ResultedDate;
    }
  }
```

Comment: pls create a stack blitz and post a link here

Comment: @Ravikumar link added

Comment: its not in edit mode!

Comment: have you tried to put this code in ngafterviewchecked?

Comment: No.Where should i use this